# Vector2 геометрия

Tags: unity3d

Как получить новый объект вектора, которой должен быть равен "первый вектор" + n градусов?

Или как получить объект вектора перпендикулярного к текущему?
Есть ли способ для получения угла между векторами с учетом знака? (как я понял, angle всегда возвращает положительное значение)

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться штатным механизмом вращения через кватернионы / матрицы:

```
// Стартовый вектор для поворота.
Vector2 start = new Vector2 (10f, 0f);
// Угол поворота в градусах, >0 - против часовой, <0 - по часовой.
float angle = 90f;
Vector2 end = Quaternion.Euler (0f, 0f, angle) * start;
// end - (0f, 10f)
```

На выходе будет правильно повернутый вектор. Для получения перпендикулярного вектора следует вращать на +/-90 градусов, в зависимости от ситуации.